# MobilePush SDK - In-App Messages implementing

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Does anyone having experiences with implement MobilePush SDK for In-App Messages? Our developing team is chewing the learning app but it doesn't specific the method that SDK handle In-App Messages from MC server.

After debugging our implemented app, we have these,

> 2019-11-13 17:42:04.310663+0700 beCustomer[2548:500818] [migration] blocking MarketingCloudSDKMigration via control channel payload
>   {
>       nodes =     (
>                   {
>               items =             {
>                   blocked = 0;
>               };
>               name = blocked;
>               version = 1;
>           },
>                   {
>               items =             (
>               );
>               name = inAppMessages;
>               version = 1;
>           },
>                   {
>               items =             (
>               );
>               name = triggers;
>               version = 1;
>           }
>       );
>   }

Without Messages ID or display any messages on the app.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The only real thing you need to do to support IAM is to handle the results from any of the CTA clicks.  For instance, in the Learning App's SDK initialization you will see that we set [a URL handler](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/blob/master/app/src/basic/java/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/learningapp/LearningApplication.kt#L46) and you can see the simplest possible [implementation of the interface](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/learningapp/BaseLearningApplication.kt#L114).

You can also find [details about implementing these methods](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html#required-methods) in our [docs](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/url-handling.html) which show more robust handling of clicks, URLs and how to ensure you have analytics for click events.

You should be receiving a payload similar to the following:

```
{
    "nodes": [{
        "version": 1,
        "name": "blocked",
        "items": {
            "blocked": 0
        }
    }, {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "inAppMessages",
        "items": [{
            "id": "MTIyNjoxMTQ6MDpyZDdKRXdZV0VlcWk1eFFDN1pPTk9R",
            "activityInstanceId": "81e13d5b-1845-491d-a12b-06548443857e",
            "startDateUtc": "2019-11-13T13:08:00.000Z",
            "modifiedDateUtc": "2019-11-13T13:08:24.000Z",
            "displayCount": 0,
            "displayLimit": 1,
            "priority": 999,
            "type": "full",
            "windowColor": "0xA1000000",
            "backgroundColor": "0xFFFFFFFF",
            "borderWidth": "s",
            "borderColor": "0xFF000000",
            "cornerRadius": "s",
            "media": {
                "url": "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/566167-best-android-apps.jpg?thumb=y&width=810&height=456",
                "size": "e2e",
                "borderWidth": "s",
                "borderColor": "0xFF000000",
                "cornerRadius": "s"
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Pro Alia",
                "fontSize": "l",
                "fontColor": "0xFF000000",
                "alignment": "center"
            },
            "body": {
                "text": "non pellentesque accommodare vidisse esse alia aliquet indoctum mus aliquip mollis ligula dicit fastidii volumus decore consequat at aptent augue convallis quod patrioque nobis invenire per",
                "fontSize": "m",
                "fontColor": "0xFF000000",
                "alignment": "center"
            },
            "closeButton": {
                "alignment": "end"
            },
            "buttonConfiguration": "stacked",
            "buttons": [{
                "id": "ef4514ca-9a37-4c41-b024-ead97a20f652",
                "index": 0,
                "text": "Button #1",
                "fontSize": "s",
                "fontColor": "0xFF000000",
                "actionType": "url",
                "actionIos": "http://www.salesforce.com",
                "actionAndroid": "http://www.salesforce.com",
                "backgroundColor": "0xFFFFFFFF",
                "borderWidth": "m",
                "borderColor": "0xFF000000",
                "cornerRadius": "s"
            }],
            "layoutOrder": "ImageTitleBody"
        }]
    }, {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "triggers",
        "items": [{
            "id": "MTIyNjoxMTQ6MDpyZDdKRXdZV0VlcWk2eFFDN0pPTk9R_PI",
            "key": "$appOpen",
            "rules": [{
                "index": 0,
                "key": "$openCount",
                "valueType": "INT",
                "value": "1",
                "operator": "GTEQ"
            }],
            "outcomes": [{
                "id": "MTIyNjoxMTQ6MDpyZDdKRXdZV0VlcWk1fFFDN0pPTk9R",
                "activityInstanceId": "81e13d5b-1845-492d-a12a-06548443857e",
                "type": "iam"
            }],
            "startDateUtc": "2019-11-13T13:08:00.000Z"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Which would display this message on next app launch:

[image]

Comment: But before handling CTA, the app needs to receive the IAM, the thing here is that the app hasn't received any Message ID nor picture.

Comment: Oh, I recognized that your payload was empty :).  You probably have a list creation/audience issue on the server side that is not going to be code-based at all, but your question specifically asks about what is required, in your application, to implement the SDK for in-app messages.

Comment: Oh, I have submitted the case. Let see the support team then since I have issue on Contact Builder data design view and structure.